# Count repetitions of repetitive events in org mode agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have my classes scheduled using diary style time intervals like this:

```
* 10:30-13:00 Classes
    <%%(and (diary-block 3 7 2016 6 29 2016) (= 3 (calendar-day-of-week date)) (not (diary-block 3 25 2016 4 1 2016)) (not (calendar-date-equal '(4 6 2016) date)))>
```

They are shown in agenda correctly like:

```
school:    10:30-13:00 Classes                                    :tag1:tag2::
```

I want to count its repetitions and make repetition count visible in agenda view this way (or similar):

```
school:    (12/23): 10:30-13:00 Classes                           :tag1:tag2::
```

By the way, this wanted format in agenda is already available when you make an event that extends over few days in a row. So, this:

```
* Some
  <2016-04-10 sun>--<2016-04-13 wed>
```

will show up in agenda just like I want:

```
school:   (3/4):  Some
```

How to make my classes event show its repetition count in agenda view?